# Spring(-Boot) & Vaadin - Set default-view in Vaadin navigator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

first of all I have here a simple UI which has a addMenueItem() Method. This method gets a view-id and adds a button to the menue and tells the navigator from  Vaadin to navigate to it on click:

```
.........
    @PostConstruct
    private void initPage() {
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
        contentLayout.setSizeFull();
    }

    protected void addMenuItem(final String viewId) {
        final String postfix;
        if (viewId == null || viewId.trim().isEmpty()) {
            postfix = "";
        } else {
            postfix = "." + viewId;
        }
        final String name = messageByLocaleService.getMessage(I18N_PREFIX + postfix);
        menue.addItem(name, menueCommand -> getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewId));
    }
.........
```

So I'm adding some views from my MainUI like:

```
addMenuItem(DefaultView.VIEW_ID);
```

The Spring url based view resolver calls the now the id from the value of 'DefaultView.VIEW_ID'. Now I'm looking for a good solution to map a given view-id not only to ' /VIEW-ID ' but also to the application root path --> ' / '.

How can I tell Spring that this special ViewID is also the root or an synonym for /VIEW-ID ?

For sure there is a possibility to hard-code this in some kind of xml-file of  Tomcat or something, but i would like to do so dynamically.

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm very new to spring and this kind of stuff, courtesy please :D

Comment: In short `""` (empty string) matches the default view as there's no URI fragment when accessing the root path. You can read more about the navigator in the [vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) and [in the vaadin wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=Vaadin+Spring) you can find a tutorial on vaadin & spring boot.

Answer (score 4):

The navigator and the URI fragment go hand in hand. The root path does not have any URI fragment therefore the navigator does not know where to navigate when the URL is called.

You can solve that problem in your UI class like this:

```
@SpringUI
public class MainUI extends UI {
    @Autowired
    SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request){
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this,this);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
        this.setNavigator(navigator);

        // Set default view
        NavigationStateManager stateManager = new Navigator.UriFragmentManager(getPage());
        stateManager.setState(DefaultView.VIEW_ID);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Most of the stuff should be well known already because these are basics that can be read in several tutorials, e.g.: [III Views and Navigation with Vaadin Spring](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring)

In short:

- You use the **@SpringUI** annotation, which by default maps to **/**, to register a new UI
- You autowire the **SpringViewProvider** which automatically registers your views.
- You initialize the navigator.

To set the default view you simply initialize the **NavigationStateManager** which sets the URI fragment. Once the init method completes the UI class calles the **Navigator.navigateTo()** method with the current state of the **NavigationStateManager**.

**NOTE:** You might find something in the net like:

```
navigator.navigateTo(DefaultView.VIEW_ID);
```

If you use this in the init method of the UI your navigator is called twice.

Comment: In Vaadin Spring 1.1 Navigator configuration became a bit simpler, maybe we should update this answer? I made this example how to move from 1.0 style to 1.1 style Navigator initialization: https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-spring-navigation-example/commit/e9bffd7b0e440541a3bc7e6948a503dcfea18523

Comment: This solution breaks bookmarks, as the navigation state is **always** set to the default view