# Navigator in Vaadin - Trying to navigate to an unknown state

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin8

I have one UI class:

```
@SpringUI(path="order")
@Title("order")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="order")
@EntityScan(basePackages="order")
public class OrderGUI extends UI {
     Navigator navigator;
     navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
     navigator.addView("getOrderNumber", GetOrderNumber.class); //also tried navigator.addView("getOrderNumber", new GetOrderNumber());
```

then when I try to navigate to `getOrderNumber` after button click:

```
navigator.navigateTo("getOrderNumber");
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state '' and an error view provider not present
```

My view where I try to go is:

```
@SpringView
@Title("Order number")
public class GetOrderNumber extends VerticalLayout implements View {
```

why does it try to go to '' when I added view 'getOrderNumber'?

@Edit
Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state '' and an error view provider not present
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:661) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:776) ~[vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:224) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:76) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.3.1.jar:8.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:356) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

@Edit
A new class which is artificial HomePage:

```
package order;

import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringView;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringView(name="")
@Component
public class HomePage extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public HomePage()
    {
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("order");
    }
}
```

but now it is throwing the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homePage' defined in file [/home/mwalko/IdeaProjects/pyszne/target/classes/order/HomePage.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [order.HomePage]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: See discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841698/pass-and-receive-data-in-vaadin/49842201

Comment: > Trying to navigate to an unknown state ''
This tells you that your are trying to navigate to view named "" which does not exists.

Comment: The stacktrace would be interesting.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich added

Comment: Where do you initialize your navigator? In constructor? Also, I recommend using SpringNavigator.

Comment: Tried in constructor and tried in `init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest)` nothing change. I'll take a look at SpringNavigator

Answer (score 2):

When does this happens? By default, the view navigator uses the URL fragment part after the `!` character to obtain the View name to display. So, in order to display the `GetOrderNumber` view, you should use an URL like this (supposing your application is deployed in the root context at `localhost` using the 8080 port):

```
http://localhost:8080/order/#!get-order-number
```

If you do not specify an explicit view name using the `name` attribute (for example `@SpringView(name="myname")`), the view name is derived from the View class name, using a "-" character at *camel* style word breaks.

Probably your navigation error occurs if you call the "base" url, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/order
```

In this case, the view navigator tries to display a view with an empty name, because the view name is missing in the URL fragment part.

Furthermore, if you use the `@SpringView` annotations you should also use the Vaadin `SpringNavigator` to consistently handle the view lifecycle and navigation, instead of the default `Navigator` one.

Regarding the empty view name problem, in the Open Source project I manage, the [Holon Platform](https://holon-platform.com/), we introduced a [@DefaultView](https://docs.holon-platform.com/current/reference/holon-vaadin.html#VaadinSpring) annotation for the Spring View Navigator to face this annoying problem, in order to declare the View to be displayed when the view name is not provided.

You can check [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/holon-platform/holon-examples/tree/master/ui-vaadin/simple-app) on how to use the `@DefaultView` annotation in a Vaadin application configured using Spring Boot.

**UPDATE:**

The default Navigator implementation uses the `Navigator.UriFragmentManager` class to handle the View display logic, so it react to any URL fragment change just after the Navigator is bound to an `UI` (so including the first servlet call to show the UI).

I think you have two main ways to get around this behavior:

**1.** Provide a View mapped to an *empty* name, using `""` as View name, to act as a "home page" View

**2.** Provide your own implementation of the `com.vaadin.navigator.NavigationStateManager` interface, avoiding to fire a view display event for empty URL fragments, and provide it to your `Navigator` instance using the `Navigator(UI ui, NavigationStateManager stateManager, ViewDisplay display)` constructor. So, in your code, you should construct the Navigator like this:

```
navigator = new Navigator(this, myNavigationStateManager, new SingleComponentContainerViewDisplay(this));
```

Furthermore, if you want a complete and consistent integration with Spring, you should use the `SpringNavigator` implementation. See http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/

Comment: This error occurs when I go to `@SpringUI(path="order")` - type `http://localhost:8080/order` in urlbar , it's throwed once and then everything is okey. Then when I navigateTo any `@SpringView` navigator works without any errors.

Comment: Hi @Michu93, if your UI is mapped to the `order` path, calling `http://localhost:8080/order` does not specify any view name (it is the root UI path), for this reason the Navigator tries to display a View with an empty name, which is not available and the error is thrown. You can either call directly your View using `http://localhost:8080/order#!get-order-number` or calling `Navigator.setState("get-order-number")` or `Navigator.navigateTo(...)` in your `UI.init()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059365/spring-boot-vaadin-set-default-view-in-vaadin-navigator#38849611

Comment: This is the reason we introduced the `@DefaultView` annotation in https://holon-platform.com, to easily solve this annoying issue

Comment: you found the bug :D when I added `stateManager.setState("order");` then error have changed to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state 'order' and an error view provider not present`. So that's it. Unfortunatelly in my application OrderGUI is `@SpringUI` so can't implement `View`. Should the first class be just Navigator which redirect to started site? Riccardo I strongly belive that holon-platform is really good but I am not familiar even with Vaadin yet so I don't want to change.

Comment: @Michu93 I understand your point, I edited my answer trying to suggest you some workarounds!

Comment: It's a vicious circle. I created HomePage with `@SpringView(name="")` then Vaadin forced me to `@Override Component getViewComponent()`. What should it return? Can I somehow make Component from View? If I just could go somehow to `@SpringUI(path="order")` that would be fine

Comment: Some progress - I have extended VerticalLayout which let me ommit `@Override getViewComponent()` but        `getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("order");` is throwing `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homePage': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.`

Comment: Can you provide the code and the stack trace? This way I willingly try to help you

Comment: question edited. I am not sure if it's not better to change this Vaadin's Navigator to SpringNavigator.